# extracting data from a text file (python)

Tags: python, split, strip

i have two columns of numbers in a text file which is the columns of time and  stress respectively which i get it from an analysis in abaqus finite element package ! i want to extract the time column and stress column in seperate lists ( a list for time and another list for stress ) . and then use this lists to do some other mathematical operations and  . . . 
my problem is how to create this lists ! my text file is as follows : **(the first line of the text file and the four lines from the bottom of that is empty!)**

```
              X               FORCE-1     

            0.                 0.         
           10.E-03            98.3479E+03 
           12.5E-03          122.947E+03  
           15.E-03           147.416E+03  
           18.75E-03         183.805E+03  
           22.5E-03          215.356E+03  
           26.25E-03         217.503E+03  
           30.E-03           218.764E+03  
           33.75E-03         219.724E+03  
           37.5E-03          220.503E+03  
           43.125E-03        221.938E+03  
           51.5625E-03       228.526E+03  
           61.5625E-03       233.812E+03
```

Comment: what is the problem while reading file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read your file line by line

```
time = []
stress = []
count =0
with open("textfile.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip() #removing extra spaces
        temp = line.split(" ")
        if count>=3 and temp[0].strip() : #checking empty string as well
           time.append(temp[0].strip())  #removing extra spaces and append
           stress.append(temp[len(temp)-1].strip()) #removing extra spaces and append
        count+=1

print time
```

**Output running above script**

```
['0.', '10.E-03', '12.5E-03', '15.E-03', '18.75E-03', '22.5E-03', '26.25E-03', '30.E-03', '33.75E-03', '37.5E-03', '43.125E-03', '51.5625E-03', '61.5625E-03']
```

Comment: It seems like you are trying to print `temp` variable

Comment: I can't prepare everything and serve you. Same code is working for me. If your are writing any code, you need to have basics  clear at least how to execute the code.

Comment: thank you for your nice replay , i approximately got my answer , but when i execute your program , i have one empty element before the first element ('0') and have four empty element after the last element ('1') . . . could you please tell how could i get ride of that elements ? Thanx

Comment: You are getting first element `0` because there is an entry. If you want to skip that part then change `count>=2` to `count>=3`